# Rails controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller

I have a controller action that is calling a model method to render some data. The controller looks something like this

```
class WeekController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @week = Week.first
  end

  def render
    Week.render
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Currently my Week.render method has a bug in it and is causing errors. Which is fine, however when I am calling my index action the page fails because of the error in my render action.

Is it normal for rails to call actions other than the one being called or is there something weird going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to call other actions as long as you don't call `redirect_to` or `render` multiple times in a response.

By the way `render` is a reserved word, and you should *not* use it for a custom method.

Comment: But by default the actions work in isolation? Like I should look into why my render method (render being a reserved word might even be the cause) is getting called?

Comment: There's no such thing. The usual `render` you call on controller actions is a standard method call.